# Databrick using "when otherwise" question

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a databrick query that I'm working on whereas I need to query a column that has been previously had `explode_outer` ran on it because the column contains json.

My issue is sometimes when I run the query I don't have any data in the column I think the schema is inferred as being a string type instead of a struct.

I was trying to get around this by using the following query...

```scala
var transformedDf = pmDf.select(
   $"_workflow".getItem("Action") as "Action", 
   when($"LeadOrganisation".isNull, null).otherwise(
        $"LeadOrganisation".getItem("Code")) as "test"
).where(col("Action") === "Put Project Live")
    
display(transformedDf)
```

but i get the following error, it looks like it runs the "otherwise" part when I don't want it too.

```
AnalysisException: Can't extract value from LeadOrganisation#84612: need struct type but got string
```

My thinking was that I would only try and drill down into the LeadOrganisation col if it wasn't null, but this seems to happen even when it is null, is there another way?

Comment: it looks like you have a problem with types. Can you check that `LeadOrganisation` is a struct, and not a string? do `pmDf.printSchema()`

Comment: when I use printschema I can see that it is marked as Struct if I have data, my issue is sometimes I have no data so then it is inferred as a string, I hoped by using "when" I could just ignore the value if it was null, but it doesn't seem to work that way

Comment: what is the input format? JSON? anyway it's better to either specify schema, or if it's streaming then use autoloader that supports schema evolution

Comment: yes the format is Json

Comment: @Martin, can you provide your schema and a sample input?

Comment: @Martin Need more details to check on the issue